# How to parse JSONArray with variable key (GSON)?

Tags: android, json, gson

My json is :

```
{"array":[{"US":"id_123"},{"UK":"id_112"},{"EN":"id_1112"}...]}
```

My classes are:

```
class LocaleResponce implements Serializable{
    @SerializedName("array")
    List<Locale> array;
}


class Locale implements Serializable{
    @SerializedName("title")
    String title;
    @SerializedName("id")
    String id;
}
```

I'm tried to make this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<LocaleResponce >(){}.getType();
LocaleResponce response = gson.fromJson(cacheJsonObject.toString(), type);
```

**it doesn't work** or is it an issue of server?

Comment: It doesn't work because your json doesn't have `title` and `id`. If you have control over json better to change it like `{"title":"US", "id":"id_123"}`

Comment: I think you can use a `HashMap` if you have variable keys.

Answer (score 4):

It can be achieved by creating custom JsonDeserializer.
Your deserializer class will look something like

```
public class CityListDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<List<City>>{

        @Override
        public List<City> deserialize(JsonElement element, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
            List<City> cityList = new ArrayList<>();

            JsonObject parentJsonObject = element.getAsJsonObject();
            Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry = parentJsonObject.entrySet().iterator().next();

            Iterator<JsonElement> iterator = entry.getValue().getAsJsonArray().iterator();
            City city;
            while (iterator.hasNext()){
                JsonObject cityJsonObject = iterator.next().getAsJsonObject();
                for(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry1 : cityJsonObject.entrySet()){
                    city = new City();
                    city.cityName = entry1.getKey();
                    city.id = entry1.getValue().toString();
                    cityList.add(city);
                }
            }
            return cityList;
        }
    }
```

You can use it with

```
try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject("{\"array\":[{\"US\":\"id_123\"},{\"UK\":\"id_112\"},{\"EN\":\"id_1112\"}]}");
            GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
            builder.registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<ArrayList<City>>() {}.getType(), new CityListDeserializer());
            Gson gson = builder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES).create();
            List<City> cityList = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(object), new TypeToken<ArrayList<City>>() {}.getType());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Your City class will be

```
public class City {
        String cityName;
        String id;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate classes for Json using websites like http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ etc in your case the `array` array variable, does not have an array of homogeneous objects `{"US":"id_123"},{"UK":"id_112"},{"EN":"id_1112"}` these are all objects of different `DataTypes` because, the parameter keys are different, so for parsing this you cannot use a Pojo. The parameters vary from UK US EN etc, the solution here is either to ask the person who is developing the api to send Json that is Consistent, the array that you have received is not type safe, if you want to use this in Java you have to write lots of lines of code. For example you can get the value of the parameter "UK" like this

```
cacheJsonObject.get("array").getAsJsonArray().get(1).get("UK").getAsString();
```

This would return the value `id_112` for instance.